# Is KLMN a rectangle

Tags: geometry

Let ABCD be a parallelogram such that AB > BC. Let K and M be the points of tangency of the circles inscribed in the triangles ACD and ABC with the side AC. Let L and N be the points of tangency points of the circles inscribed in the triangles BCD and ABD with the side BD. Is KLMN a rectangle?

I tried hard but I couldn't find it. I proved that KLMN must be a paralellogram by the symmetry of the triangles but i could not prove that it must be a rectangle

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: did you try to sketch it with some geometrie software, wher you can easely  change parameters?

Comment: If KLMN is parallelogram, then KM = LN. Let O is center of ABCD, then KO = LO. There is formula for AK in terms of AB, BC, AC. Then you can express KO and check if it depends on AC. If KO depends on AC, then LO can be other than KO, because for LO AC should be substituted with BD.

Answer (score -1):

[image]

Hint: In figure EF, GF, GH and HE are perpendicular on BD, AC, BD and AC at points  L. M, N and K respectively. Now you can either say quadrilateral KLMN is cyclic so it is rectangle.Or say quadrilateral EFGH is a rhombus ; KL and MN are perpendicular on diagonal EG, also LM and NK are parallel to it, so KLMN is rectangle.